# How to connect to MySQL using ssh tunnel with perl

Tags: mysql, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel

I am using Amazon EC2 instance of MySQL and need to modify my perl scripts to connect to the database using ssh tunnel (instead of the plain old hostname:port). Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really a Perl problem -- just set up an ssh tunnel so that the apparent mysql location is the address of your tunnel.

Comment: if you find an answer that helps you, click the tick next to it so that others can find the right answer in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after establishing SSH tunnel connection differs only with hostname and it's 127.0.0.1 (localhost) in that moment

Answer (score 3):

Open a tunnel:

```
ssh -fNL 3306:localhost:3306 myname@myhost
```

Then connect to localhost:3306

Answer (score 1):

MySQL attempts to map localhost[:port] connections to use a local (UNIX) socket; you should use 127.0.0.1 for a tcp/ip socket.

Answer (score 0):

One note in regard to answer by chris - on some setups "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" make a difference. In my case, localhost didn't work, while 127.0.0.1 did work flawlessly.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about ssh but you can [encrypt connections between your application and your DB Instance using SSL](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#53), would that be sufficent for you?

Comment: Not exactly the same. The connections will be encrypted, but you're still exposing your mysql port.

Comment: I actually don't care to encrypt, but Amazon AWS allows remote machines to connect to their EC2 instance only through SSH tunnel. So for example, I was able to connect mysql workbench on my local machine to the EC2 mysql server using workbench's connect option (TCP/IP over ssh), in which one has to specify the ssh hostname (with key pair) and the database hostnames (on localhost with username/password) separately. I am guessing there should be a similar mechanism with perl dbi connect.

Comment: By default I think only port 22 is open for ec2 instances. You can open up the Mysql port by changing the security group in the ec2 management console.