# Perl DBI cannot connect on localhost, but mysql client can

Tags: mysql, perl

I use a ssh local tunnel on Ubuntu, port 33061

This works :

```
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33061 -u myuser -p'Rsre45%!epz67az' [-D db]
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 115342288
Server version: 8.0.32-commercial MySQL Enterprise Server - Commercial

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

But not this :

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$host;port=33061", $userLogin, $userPass)
```

Using "localhost", I get an Access denied from the mysql server and using "127.0.0.1", the connection try hangs

```
$grep localhost /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

$grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
$
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4197253/2173773

Comment: Thanks Hakon, even if I make the tunnel listen on all interfaces, the issue remains 
`-L *:33061:$hostssh`

Comment: Very strange,  a tcpdump on target shows mysql exchanges with $hostssh when I use the mysql client, but nothing with Perl, despite the error : `Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`, who does answer me ?

Comment: What does an _strace_ show you perl is doing?

Comment: strace done. There's also a mysqld running in my server, and the perl seems to connect to it, as if the port parameter was not seen 
`connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, 110) = 0
sendto(3, "\351\0\0\1\217\2 .....
recvfrom(3, "&\0\0\2\376sha256_password\0ndg\23 ....`

Comment: Typically `3306x` port is just for the MySQL "shell" (and other MySQL specific things), try port `3306` with `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I don't care the local mysqld running at standard port 3306, I want my perl to use my tunnel on 33061 :  
`mysqld     242 1021 connectio      mysql   23u     IPv6              19846       0t0        TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
ssh       1012                   fr25155    4u     IPv4                770       0t0        TCP *:33061 (LISTEN)
ssh       1012                   fr25155    5u     IPv6                771       0t0        TCP *:33061 (LISTEN)` see the dbi connect above. As if the port number 33061 was not seen.

Comment: Just try with a smaller port (5000), save behavior, not seen in the connection api.

Comment: @troubadour, please _strace_ the one going to 127.0.0.1.  (My recollection is that dbd::mysql and perhaps mysql APIs always understand "localhost" to mean the local UNIX socket, and not the network address.)  That hang might be a network timeout, DNS lookup, etc.

Comment: I came here to mention that I seem to remember the MySQL client falling back to a unix socket when connecting to 127.0.0.1. Your trace confirms this. (`sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"`) I suspect your MySQL server isn't configured to listen to IPv6 or IPv4, only to the unix socket. So you'll need to 1) switch to connection to the unix socket, or 2) configure the MySQL server to listen to IPv4 (`127.0.0.1`) and/or IPv6 (`::1`, and I suspect `localhost`).

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#port All comments here converges to the same conclusion already. But I just want to refer to the documentation of `DBD::mysql`. This is a documented behaviour and the documented solution is: use the loopback IP address instead.